# JQuery Cookie is becoming invalidated across different directories?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have a basic theming system built into my site, that uses a jQuery cookie to maintain the currently selected theme. However, it seems that when I visit other directories on my site, the theme changes back to the default.

I watch my cookies from within chrome's cookie store, and it seems a session level cookie is being created, read, and overwrites my other cookies. Any ideas?

```
var handleThemeSkins = function () {
    // Handle theme colors
    var setSkin = function (color) {
        $('#skin-switcher').attr("href", "/Content/themes/" + color + ".css");
        if ($.cookie('skin_color')) {
            $.cookie('skin_color', color, { expires: 365, path: '/' });
        }
    }
    $('ul.skins > li a').click(function () {
        var color = $(this).data("skin");
        setSkin(color);
    });

    if ($.cookie('skin_color')) {
        setSkin($.cookie('skin_color'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the cookie is being set at all?

Comment: Yup, because if i visit pages from within the same directory, the theme sticks.

Comment: are the dirs on other domains, for example dom1.yourserver.com/page1 vs dom2.yourserver.com/page2

Comment: Are you sure you're not just setting the cookie again?

Comment: This is all running from localhost. So that shouldn't affect anything. The cookie shouldn't be being set again, or at least if it is, it should be set to the currently selected cookie.